# Transfer indexed Oracle geoloc table to PostgreSQL using ogr2ogr

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ogr2ogr, oracle-spatial, spatial-index

I am copying tables using ogr2ogr from Oracle to PostGIS using

```
 ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"host=<host> port=5432 user=<user> dbname=<dbname> password=<pwd>" OCI:<USERNAME>/<PASSWORD>@<SID>:<table>
```

This command fails to copy indexed tables, but works on regular tables.

```
ERROR 1: ERROR: permission denied for relation spatial_ref_sys when copying <table>@AWS
```

This might be related to https://github.com/hdknr/note/issues/11

---

Update: By indexing I mean these commands in Oracle:

```
INSERT INTO user_sdo_geom_metadata VALUES ('my_table', 'GEOLOC',  MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ARRAY(
  MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('X', -180, 180, 0.0005),
  MDSYS.SDO_DIM_ELEMENT('Y', -90, 90, 0.0005)),  8307 );
--Commit  
CREATE INDEX my_table_IX ON my_table(GEOLOC)  INDEXTYPE IS MDSYS.SPATIAL_INDEX PARAMETERS ('SDO_INDX_DIMS=2')
```

What is the right way to copy an indexed table?

Comment: I can't imagine any possible reason why an index could have any possible impact on a full-scanning SELECT statement.

Comment: @Vince It might be related to https://github.com/hdknr/note/issues/11

Comment: @Vince when you ran the OGR2OGR statement on your Oracle to PostGIS connection, did you have any issues on your indexed tables, or did they all come across OK?

Comment: @Vince When a table is NOT indexed it is copied correctly. When an index is added with `CREATE INDEX`  (see updated question) it returns an error.

Comment: @Stepan You seem to be focusing on the wrong end of the process. It's not the Oracle side that's in difficulty, but the PostgreSQL side. Try to load a 10-row shapefile or CSV into the PG instance; if that fails, you can isolate your `spatial_ref_sys` problem.